# How does Sorting Layer work *under the hood*?

Tags: unity, sprites

I know how to use SpriteRendere's `Sorting Layer` and `Order in Layer`. But how do they actually work under the hood? How the render pipeline gets this information? Is there a "sprite sorter" to sort all the sprites before rendering every frame? Or are the mesh's Z changes? Or the sorting layer info is written to z-buffer for alpha blend?

Comment: You can confirm it's not Z because sorting layers and Z sorting interact. You can confirm it's not the depth buffer because it works with partial translucency. So, doesn't that just leave the option listed right in the name: they're sorted for rendering order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answered from Unity staff:](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-does-sorting-layer-work-under-the-hood.1362403/)

> Before rendering, all the renderers are sorted in order before they
> are rendered. For renderers in the Transparent Queue, they are sorted
> using the Sorting Layer and Order first before the other criteria (See
> https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DSorting.html). The sorted renderer
> list is then passed to the render pipeline for batching and rendering.
> The sorted renderer order is not written to the Z-buffer.
>
> All renderers do have a Sorting Layer and Order in Layer, even if you
> may not see it in their respective Inspectors (See
> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sortingOrder.html).
> You could use that to order your Renderer if you are not using a
> SpriteRenderer.